# How to store cms article content

Tags: content-management-system, article

Basically i have requirement to build a CMS kind of site.
if user submits a article what is the best way to store the article. whether it is xml or database.
the article will contain rich text formatting like content,images,highlighting source code.
sample article looks like http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1498-how-to-work-with-or-create-master-pages-in-aspnet-.aspx. Take this article as example which has images,content, source code highlighting and rich text formats. so how to store this kind of content to our website.
please guide me best way of how to store.

Comment: I have the exact same question and found somehow a solution for it. you may consider [taking a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536231/put-markup-in-articles-in-php-mysql-website)

Answer (score 3):

If you are planning to implement a CMS I would strongly recommend that you look at the open source CMSs that are out there before you start rolling your own.

WordPress, Joomla! and Drupal are the big three CMS and would be able to do all the things you have suggested.

On the issue of whether to store in the database or as files or has had an answer here:  [CMS: store custom pages as files or in MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384465/cms-store-custom-pages-as-files-or-in-mysql-database)

The question of whether images should be stored in a db vs filesystem is a recurring theme and this seems to be one of the best QandAs on it

[Store pictures as files or in the database for a web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561447/store-pictures-as-files-or-in-the-database-for-a-web-app)

Comment: I want to build my own custom CMS kind of site not to use open source. so please tell me which is the best option to store the content. like how to store images, content...etc

Comment: from the link in the answer.  "You'd be better off storing content in the database. Note that you store content, not the entire HTML page (otherwise, you're not really building a content management system)."